# how to highlight and convert text (in UILabel) to a clickable link/button in IOS8 swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

I am new to iOS. 
In my project I have a post that can be used to mention persons as below:

```
"Hola @toni e @sophea estoy muy contento".
```

What is the best way to render this as an `UILabel` with all words starting with @ (@toni, @sophea) highlighted and clickable with some `IBAction` handler. This is pretty simple in html and js but I could not figure out how to do it with swift iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TTTAttributedLabel. It can probably do everything you want. UILabel itself is relatively limited.

https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UITextView, sets its attributedString property to one that has links in it.  The UITextView will need to have its recognize link property turned on, and scrolling turned off.  You'll need to either create the links in code, or you can create HTML and convert it to NSAttributedString.

```
   // Converting HTML to attributed string
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let options: [String:Any] = [
                NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
            ]
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return  nil
        }
    }
}
```